# F_mount function is not working with STM32F401ReTx

Tags: c, stm32, sd-card, stm32f4

I have written some simple code (with the help of STM32CubeMx) for STM32F407VGTx to create a file in SDcard. Although it works perfectly with 407, it is not working with STM32F401ReTx. To be clear, I have generated code with CubeMx specifically for 401(did not use the code for 407).

Even for 407, I am able to work with only Version 21 of CubeMx and firmware version 16. I have added the code below. Any ideas?

```
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SDIO_SD_Init();
  MX_FATFS_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  if(f_mount(&myFatFS,SD_Path,1)==FR_OK)
  {
      HAL_Delay(1000);
      f_open(&myFil,"new document.txt\0",FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
      f_close(&myFil);
  }

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably heap size f407 has more initial heap size than f401. Try to increase heap size in linker file.